# How can I remove this file?

Tags: filesystem, cifs, gvfs, rm, filename

I'm using an Apple Timecapsule mounted via `gvfs-mount` (I tried `cifs` too) which contains a file named

> Capitoli 3:5.odt

I definitely want to remove that but I had no luck.

From ubuntu the most i can get is "File o directory non esistente" (which is italian for "No such file or directory", I suppose) from windows it doesn't let me manage this file because : (colon) is forbidden

I tried removing that file using the inode, but still no luck.

I'm mounting the share using these options `sec=ntlm,serverino,nodfs`

This is what i get:

```
# ls -l
totale 16
-rwxr-xr-x 0 root root 15296 ago 19  2008 Capitoli 3:5.odt
# rm -f Capitoli\ 3\:5.odt
# ls -l
totale 16
-rwxr-xr-x 0 root root 15296 ago 19  2008 Capitoli 3:5.odt
```

With the `-f` option rm behaves as if the file was effectively removed, which is not the case. Without that option it says

```
# rm Capitoli\ 3\:5.odt
rm: impossibile rimuovere "Capitoli 3:5.odt": File o directory non esistente
```

which means like "No such file or directory".

Any advice on how to remove this haunting presence in my device?

This is the content of `/proc/fs/cifs/DebugData` that I think could be useful:

```
Display Internal CIFS Data Structures for Debugging
---------------------------------------------------
CIFS Version 2.0
Features: dfs fscache lanman posix spnego xattr acl
Active VFS Requests: 0
Servers:
1) Name: 192.168.1.1  Domain: WORKGROUP Uses: 1 OS: Apple Base Station
    NOS: CIFS 4.32  Capability: 0x207c
    SMB session status: 1   TCP status: 1
    Local Users To Server: 1 SecMode: 0x3 Req On Wire: 0
    Shares:
    1) \\192.168.1.1\disco Mounts: 1 Type: FAT32 DevInfo: 0x0 Attributes: 0x3
PathComponentMax: 255 Status: 0x1 type: 0 

    MIDs:
```

Comment: I added `iocharset=utf8,mapschars` to boot options, but still no luck

Comment: Try `sudo rm -f "Capitoli 3:5.odt"

Comment: I'm realizing it's not something you can fix using quotes...

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing the filename in single quotes:
    rm 'Capitoli 3:5.odt'

Comment: I thought I would work, but I tried it anyway: didn't make the trick

Comment: Have you tried using a wildcard, e.g. rm Capitoli*

Comment: Wildcards don't seem to be the solution